# Is there any tool which uses Elasticsearch API to show report or to generate report?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I want to know that is there any tool which uses **Elasticsearch** API to show report or to generate report based on the data that we have in **Elasticsearch**?

I have a bunch of log data indexed in my **Elasticsearch**, but every time I need to write **curl** query to get count of specific log type by hourly interval. I just need any tool which consists of some UI and where we can configure some settings and can get the detailed report by hour.

Note: I have **Kibana** 3 and 4. But looking for tool apart from **Kibana** to show report.

Comment: what you don't like about Kibana?

Comment: May be its because of I am new to Kibana, but I want count of log lines which contains a particular text and that too by hourly interval, but in kibana 4 when I select tabular format for visualization it shows me to select for metric. But at the same time it doesn't allow me to put condition of particular field for match. It just shows for count, Min, Max, Sum, Standard deviation etc..

Comment: Plus kibana is automatically scaling to 3 hours. :(

Comment: as for 2018 you can use [seektable.com](https://www.seektable.com) and build datagrids (with filter), charts and pivot tables by ElasticSearch (I'm developer of this tool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn how to work with Kibana. You can make visualization (lets say barchart) with date histogram per 1 hour. The data to show is filtered by query at the top of the page. Check out the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/_kibana_query_and_filter.html) and look at demo examples at http://demo.elastic.co

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Graylog](https://www.graylog.org/)? Or have a look at these [~300 resources for visualizing data](http://www.visualisingdata.com/resources/) if you find one that fits to you and has an elasticsearch connector.

Cheers!